# Unexpected <head/> tag in AJAX response

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, unexpected-token

I use ElasticSearch in my application, where further search results can be loaded under ajax calls (pagination with ajax). However, the ajax response is coming with a  tag in the beginning as it follows:

[image: Response screenshot]

When this response is appended to my HTML page, it destroys the grid because of this :

[image: Broken HTML]

I'm tempted to do a simple javascript replace in  by empty string, but I'd like to find out the real reason.

Any idea about why it happens? can it be caused by APACHE server? Please help.

Comment: Jush htmlResponse.replace('<head/>',''); :v

Comment: Check the source of the original file as AJAX returns the *entire* set of markup in the requested page.

Comment: `<head/>` is not even valid HTML, so I have to assume it  is something you have added rather then the utilities you are using

Comment: No such thing as <head/> it should be </head>

Comment: Check your source doc carefully. You may have an unclosed tag in your source document, and the closing <head> tag is getting pulled in as a result. As in, you probably have <head /> instead of </head>

Comment: Our core framework is Zend3 (PHP).. my PHTML file is ok, it starts with a <tr> and ends with </tr>.. I really don't know what's going on because it just doesn't happen on other pages that work similarly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem after finding out that Pagespeed extension is working along with Apache in our server. This extension has a filter that adds the `<head>` tag in HTML documents where it's absent. So, considering my AJAX responses being partial HTML body, this filter was automatically adding the `<head>` tag as the response content type was text/html. All I had to do was changing this content type to text/ajaxresponse in cases it was necessary. Disabling this extension ain't worthy because there might be some pages that need it.